# Creating a Box Control over an area of the map with OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, dictionary, openlayers

I am using [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) to create a box of interest with my program. I am using this code:

```
var control = new OpenLayers.Control();
OpenLayers.Util.extend(control, {
    draw: function () {
        this.box = new OpenLayers.Handler.Box( control,
            {"done": this.notice},
            {keyMask: OpenLayers.Handler.MOD_SHIFT});
        this.box.activate();
    },
    notice: function (bounds) {
        areaSelected(bounds);
    }
});
map.addControl(control);
```

to capture the "Shift Create a Box" [control](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.7/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control-js.html) and use the area selected as my area of interest. However the values come back as pixels. But I want **Longitude and Latitude**, not pixels. The Mouse Position [control](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/MousePosition-js.html) does show the correct long & lat. I really don't care how to box is created, I just want an easy way for the user to select a area of the map and I need to get the lat & longs of the area. (Box, Circle, doesn't matter)

Answer (score 0):

Check out: http://garmin.na1400.info/routable.php

It has a checkbox to set "Enable tile selection" set it.

Now when you drag a box on the map, it will select the underlying objects.

You can reuse the sourcecode. All the magic is in: http://garmin.na1400.info/routable.js

Answer (score 0):

Very late reply but my help others in the future!

I managed to get the decimal degrees from the pixels by doing the following:

```
var point1 = new OpenLayers.Pixel(bounds.left, bounds.bottom);
var point2 = new OpenLayers.Pixel(bounds.right, bounds.top);

var ll1 = map.getLonLatFromPixel(point1);
var ll2 = map.getLonLatFromPixel(point2);
```

drop that in your notice function and you'll have the lat/long pairs in ll1 & ll2!